# How to hide the progress bar when webview starts rendering the content - Android

Tags: android, webview, progress-bar

I want to hide the progress bar on webview as and when webview started rendering the content. I tried webview.getProgress() to get the current progress of webview. It returns progress in the range between 0-100. But I couldn't conclude that at which range actually webview starts render the content.

I would like to know that, Is there any method to identify the start of rendering the content in webview android.

Your help is much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add WebViewClient() and in callback methods hide progress.

```
  webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                                    String description, String failingUrl) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried using of onPageFinshed(), but it's called only after page loaded. But need to hide the progress bar before page loads. Actually i need to hide the progress bar after rendering started

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution after a lot of searching! There is a "onPageCommitVisible" method in webViewClient which does exactly this, displays the progressbar until the page renders and the disappears.

```
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageCommitVisible(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageCommitVisible(view, url);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

Hope it helps :D

Answer (score 0):

```
final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
pDialog.setMessage("Please wait....");
pDialog.setCancelable(false);
pDialog.show();

String url = "url";

final Activity activity = (Activity) context;
pdfView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)   
    {
        activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
        pDialog.incrementProgressBy(progress);
        if(progress == 100 && pDialog.isShowing()) 
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```

Dialog will dismiss when webview start rendering the content.

Answer (score 0):

```
 class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }
}


class MYWebViewChromeClient extends WebChromeClient{
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
     //When the schedule is equal to 100 of the time, that is, the load is completed, you can hide the progress bar
        super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually i need to hide the progress bar when it started rendering the content on the webview not at the end of load

Comment: can‘t you onPageFinished()?

Comment: onPageFinished() called only after page loaded